# Angular project send URL parameters to mongodb

Tags: angular, mongodb, url-parameters

I have been stuck for almost a week. Want to fetch URL parameters and send it to backend(Mongodb). Please help me. Every suggestions will be appreciated.

I am able to get URL params into HTML but want to show it in MongoDatabase. Sharing my code below

**Contact.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule, SimpleChanges, OnChanges, DoCheck, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Feedback } from '../model/feedback';
import { AuthGuardService } from '../guards/auth-guard.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.scss', './contact.component.mobile.scss']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
  //name of parameters to fetch
  // @Input() authors: AuthorModel;
  bannerid: string;
  devicetype: string;
  country: string;

  constructor(private authGuardService: AuthGuardService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private apiService: ApiService) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParam => {
      this.bannerid = queryParam.bannerid;
      this.devicetype = queryParam.devicetype;
      this.country = queryParam.country;
      console.log(queryParam);
    })
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(changes);
  }

  feedModel = new Feedback('', '', '', '', '', '', '');


  onSubmit(data): void {
    // console.log(data);
    //  console.log(this.feedModel);
    this.apiService.onSubmit(data);
    this.authGuardService.feedBack(this.feedModel);
  }
  // queryParam(latest): void{
  //   console.log(latest);
  //   this.apiService.queryParam(this.bannerid);
  // }


}
```

Comment: Like you want to get content from get url params, then fetch into a rest api to connect with mongodb ?

Comment: He Elikill, I just want to show angular app URL params in mongodb (using node.js). Example url: http://localhost:4201/contact?bannerid=4343&devicetype=desktop&country=india

Comment: and where are you stuck ? You seems to well get params. And now you don't know what to do ? If yes, it's offtopic on stack overflow as it's too board. You should check for [Rest API](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/api/what-is-a-rest-api) to be able to connect with your DB, and use [http request](https://angular.io/guide/http) to call it

Comment: Hi Elikill, Yes i am able to fetch params. It is just that i want to send it to mongodb.

Comment: @Sam you're going to have to do that on the server-side.

Comment: can you please suggest something? as I am not able to get values